# Appreciation Email: in or with: Awesome work Mark [in/with] coordinating, planning and delivering the training

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, email

One of my reports in India trained a batch of new hires in Costa Rica recently. He has received great feedback from his trainees, for e.g.

1. Thank you very much Mark for all your support and your patience; for such amazing training.
2. Mark was great during the training. He was always ready to answer our questions and he was very patient with our doubts in general. I was very pleased with the training.

I want to send a short email to Sachin and the management team to appreciate his work.

This is my draft:
Awesome work Mark in coordinating, planning and delivering the training despite different shifts and time zones.
Thank you for your efforts.

I have 2 questions -

1. Should it be work in or work with coordinating....
2. I want to add a sentence where I highlight the feedback that he has received (in the email thread). How do I do this in a sentence?

Comment: Mark did the great job or Sachin did? Forward the emails directly, not within your new thread.

Comment: You have expressed yourself clearly in your question. Apply the same ability to your appreciative email. We are not here to refine and polish others’ prose with our varied opinions.

Comment: With regard to the first question, if you want the answer you should have demonstrated some research previously done, for example [of this kind](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+in+coordinating%2Cwork+with+coordinating&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10).